# PhoneGap with SenchaTouch for Android App

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

I am facing an issue while trying to build an Android app using Sencha Touch and with PhoneGap.

I am using PhoneGap v1.2.0, Sencha Touch 2.0.0 pr3 to build a simple maps based application and get this issue.

The error logs on the console point to the Ext variable not being found (see below).

```
D/PhoneGapLog(  626): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
D/PhoneGapLog(  626): file:///android_asset/www/app.js: Line 2 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
```

I have already defined an extended timeout value for loading the URL :

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 400000); 
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

The below are the script files I am trying to load in the index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Help here would be appreciated.

Have alternately tried using the native Android packaging to build an Android app using Sencha but have run into issues around it not finding the app icon, which I am not sure as to where it should be placed in.

Comment: Cant say about the particular error but this link may be of some help http://android.amolgupta.in/2011/07/hybrid-applications-using-phonegap-and.html

Comment: Thanks, figured this out. Had an issue with one of the script tags because of which the sencha-touch library was not getting loaded up. Works now.

Comment: Please close/answer the question if you've resolved it...

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with my script tags because of which I was facing the issue.